# Items on collectionview appears twice after device rotation

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a items (buttons, labels) on cells on my uicollectionview. As soon as I rotate my device items appears twice.... I already called viewWillTransition but no effect, always the same issue.. Any idea ? Thanks! Here is my code :

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
}

public override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()

    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try reloading collectionview in viewdidlayout subviews

Comment: I solved my issue using custom cell file. Then I call (in cellForItemAt indexPath function) the label using : cell.myLabel.text = "" for example. Now my next issue is the following. This label has constraints to his contentView. Everything is placed as expected. Now if I rotate the device the position of the label in the cell is wrong regarding his constraints. How can I manage that plz? Thanks!

Comment: when you rotate . viewdidlayoutsubviews method will call. then reload collection. i have faced in one app. i fixed like this.if wont reload cells will be as it in previous orientation. thats y constraints not changing. i hop it may be the reason

Comment: You can do this by implementing the UICollectionViewDelegate method collectionView(_:targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:): During layout updates, or when transitioning between layouts, the collection view calls this method to give you the opportunity to change the proposed content offset to use at the end of the animation. You might return a new value if the layout or animations might cause items to be positioned in a way that is not optimal for your design.